# Using a base class to set page titles in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, extends, subclassing

In my angular 7 app, I want to have a base class that I can extend all route/page components from, to allow me to set the page title in a consistant way.  Right now I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible though.  Here's what I have so far:

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { PageTitleService } from '../services/page-title/page-title.service';

export abstract class BaseTitledPage {
    /**
     * This string is used to set the page title in the browser window/tab.
     * It is also generally encouraged to be used as the "title" of the page is the UI so that these titles are always in sync
     */
    protected pageTitle: string;

    protected constructor(injectedPageTitle: string) {
        this.pageTitle = injectedPageTitle;

        const injector = Injector.create({
            providers: [ {provide: PageTitleService, deps: []} ]
        });

        const pageTitleService = injector.get(PageTitleService);

        this.setPageTitle(pageTitleService, this.pageTitle);
    }

    private setPageTitle(svc: PageTitleService, title: string): void {
        svc.setPageTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Then a page would use it like this:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-page-home',
    templateUrl: './page-home.component.html'
})
export class PageHomeComponent extends BaseTitledPage {
    constructor() {
        super('Home');
    }
}
```

Ideally I could then use `{{pageTitle}}` in my template, and that would match the actual page title in the browser tab/window.

---

Is what I want to do possible here?  Can I get or inject a service in a non-component base class like this?  I know it would be possible to have that service on ever child-class and the pass it into `super('Home, pageTitleService)` but i want to avoid that if I can just to keep things simpler.

Comment: If the title depends on the routes, I would use this approach: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events subscribe to router events on the app.component.ts and get the title from a data attribute.

Comment: I started with that, but I don't like the idea of disconnected one piece of text from the rest of the component.  Ideally I'd like to set the title once and then be able to use that in both the page title and in the UI template

Comment: I definitely would follow the approach Christian linked its simple and you don't end up with repeated code. You could make a PageTitleComponent and reference it in the html of every component. Pass the title to it `<page-title [title]="title"></page-title>` through binding. No need for a base class and no need to work around angular's dependency injection

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion about the component, I think i  like that the best!. It a does seem like a better & easier way.  Thanks!